# How to use setState() function inside statelessWidget class

Tags: android, ios, flutter, customdialog, statelesswidget

I can't use `setState` function inside `dialogContent` and I got this error :

```
The method 'setState' isn't defined for the class 'CustomDialog'
```

and here I used  `setState()`

```
Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: status ? <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5,top: 0),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/profile.png',
                          width: 60.0,
                          height: 60.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                        child: Container(
                          width: 200.0,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: const Radius.circular(50.0),
                              topRight: const Radius.circular(50.0),
                              bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(50.0),
                              bottomRight: const Radius.circular(50.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                            child: Center(
                              child: Text(
                                'test',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    fontSize: 25.0
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                      child: CustomSwitch(
                        activeColor: Colors.green,
                        value: status,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          print("VALUE : $value");
                          setState(() {
                            status = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ] :
                  [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left :25.0),
                        child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                            'test',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.red,
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0),
                      child: CustomSwitch(
                        activeColor: Colors.green,
                        value: status,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          print("VALUE : $value");
                          setState(() {
                            status = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]
              ),
```

Comment: can we have the code that create this error?

Comment: @DipStax I edit the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can't use setState() in StatelessWidget, that's the idea of this widget.
StatelessWidget should be used only for "dumb" views that shouldn't hold any state.
If you should set any state to your widget, consider to use StatefulWidget.

Take a look on official flutter documentation:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html